How to match the corresponding values of Category and Amount columns?
enter image description here
I'm new to power bi.I tried split delimiter by | and it was creating multiple rows with each category matching with each amount value of the same order id. But, I want only corresponding values of the category and amount to be matched.

Could you better clarify what do you mean by corresponding values? Could you post your expected output?

not sure if we have an easier way to solve this. Here is a workaround for you as a reference.

Split the Category column by "|"


do the same for column Amount


select order id column and unpivot other columns



for the attribute column , only remain the number


use group by function to combine the text and number which the attribute is the same


remove the column attribute and split the combined column


rename the column name



let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bVC7bsMwDPwVQ3NCiLQe0egEyJoA7RZ4cF0lNmDIhmQPAfrxpWoPCdCF4h3vjgJvN3Gq9iQR92gsOid24tiHbx9T8VNUceZ67cbgMzw3afZhHV2byUcWG+nAHZjQoPJTOlyx1RqcyQwCkqh3L5uUkyTZfLnf+9YXH8s0Df26Ygn9vESfeEpbMAeqd3+JTup//Z++7cI4jI/nG2CtBWJKEUg8mK0r9WsukjWoWFq1rU9pjFtk8zX8Ndtd8s9KBUozhaQNUA5GC8qIuv4F", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Order ID" = _t, Category = _t, Amount = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Order ID", type text}, {"Category", type text}, {"Amount", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Category", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Category.1", "Category.2", "Category.3", "Category.4", "Category.5"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Amount", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Amount.1", "Amount.2", "Amount.3", "Amount.4", "Amount.5"}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter1", {"Order ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Extracted Last Characters" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {{"Attribute", each Text.End(_, 1), type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Extracted Last Characters", {"Order ID", "Attribute"}, {{"text", each Text.Combine([Value],","), type any}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter2" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "text", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"text.1", "text.2"}),
    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter2",{{"text.1", type text}, {"text.2", type number}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type4",{{"text.1", "Category"}, {"text.2", "Amount"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"

